# Angular Material: Button toogle and tooltip for enabled/disabled

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Button toggle in Material. I want to use icons and tooltips. For the disabled buttons I want to display a different tooltip than for the enabled. I tried a very simplistic approach with a `ngIf` but somehow this doesn't work:

```
<mat-button-toggle value="justify" disabled aria-label="Text align justify">
    <ng-container *ngIf="true; else noComments">
      <span  matTooltip="disabled tooltip"></span>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-icon>format_align_justify</mat-icon>
</mat-button-toggle>
```

I created as well a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz91x1). For the very first button one could see the working tooltip. My intention would be to specify the `mat-icon` only once and just change the tooltip - depending on the enable or disabled state.

Is this something which can *easily* be achieved?

Comment: I just answered this guy, 2 second ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349089/how-to-enable-mat-tooltip-if-its-host-button-is-disabled-in-angular-9-template

Comment: But I want to have two different tooltips. One for enabled and one for disabled. I don't see how this can be achieved with your approach.

Comment: how about using ngIf inside the tooltip with <span></span> ?
that an easy way for doing it.
The ngif will be about if its disabled or not.

Comment: Yeah, but than the `mat-toogle-button` won't be displayed. I found a solution with interpolation, i.e. `{{myTooltip}}`